# ng2-search-filter filter records based on column fields angular

Tags: angular, search

I am using npm i ng2-search-filter plugin to filter records . Below is the code I have used and its working fine . I installed the plugin and added ngModel called searchFinalData and passed the model name to the array list. Now its doing a global search for all the list of fields present in the array. However, I need to filter based on only two columns. How do I achieve this

```
<div>    
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="searchFinalData" placeholder="Enter Case No or Patient Name" />
                </div>
  <div *ngFor="let array of arrayitems |  filter:searchFinalData> </div

{
billStatus:"F"
caseNo:"2011000126"
clinicName:"DR WINSTON JONG"
patientName:"DEATH ANGELSEAN"
}
{
billStatus:"F"
caseNo:"1011000139"
clinicName:"DR WINSTON JONG"
patientName:"LIEWCHRISTINA Cccev eeeee"
}
```

I need to search based on case number and patient name only. How to add column name parameters to my search filter.

Comment: did you try appending the property with a colon?  Like this 
 `filter:searchFinalData:caseNo`

Comment: It didnt work . I tried to search with JONG , it provided me both the items from array. Ideally, in my case , I want to search only in caseNo and patient name fields . So it should not display both the items because case No and patient Name doesnt have JONG in it.

Comment: I believe that module searches all properties of the object. I don't see a way to restrict which properties are searched.

Comment: Cant we restrict using the column name as mentioned by @RaymondHolguin

Comment: Guys !! Is there a way to do this ??

Comment: Based on the plugins homepage it didn't appear to support this.  Either try a different plugin or build something yourself.  Something like this isn't too complicated

Comment: Ok for this I did a custom pipe and achieved it